# Change the color of a button in a row by id in a datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm using asp.net-mvc with Ajax and jQuery and what I'm struggling to get is how I can change the color of a button, in a single row of a datatable by id (or anything else possible) of that specific row only.

I used

```
 $('.btn-query-company').addClass('btn-danger');
```

and it just turns all buttons in every row which is what I don't want. I want only one button per row.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which row? What does your html for the table look like? How can anyone possible answer this without the relevant information

Comment: well if the element has an ID, you can use it, e.g. `$('#btn-20').addClass('btn-danger');` but as mentioned we have no idea what your HTML looks like so it's impossible to give specific advice. We also don't know in what context you're running this code - perhaps you can traverse the DOM to find the right element within the row, if you know the row. Much more info is needed for people to help you properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get id of row by clicking on it, and find the button using it and then apply css('color','red') to change color

```
$('#my_table_id').on('click', 'tbody td', function(e) { 
        var partiicular_row_id = $(this).parent().attr('id'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for coming back to me. Basically this is how my HTML looks:

```
<table class="table no-margin table-striped table-hover table-condensed dataTable" id="userstbl">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th>Company</th>...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@item.CompanyName</td>
            @{ 
                if (Request.Cookies["Roles"].Values["role"] != "C" && Request.Cookies["Roles"].Values["role"] != "U")
                {
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-query-company" data-id="@item.id" data-name="@item.OverallStatus" href="javascript:void(0);">Query</a>
                    </td>
                }
            }
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Off course I have more than just that one header in my real code but the styling is still the same. The `<a>` tag which represents my button is the subject of my question. I hope this helps.